# ver tablas de una dB y las columnas de esas tablas

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo el siguiente query el cual me muestra las bases de datos que tiene Sql Server

```
select * from master.dbo.sysdatabases;
```

Esto me daría las bases de datos. Por ejemplo me muestra la que busco se llama
DB_TEST.

Como seria el query para ver las tablas de DB_TEST y como sería el query para ver los campos de esas tablas?

Answer (score 1):

La forma mas compatible de consultar las tablas de una base de datos, es viendo directamente la vista `sysobjects`:

```
-- Para consultar las tablas de master
select * from master..sysobjects where xtype = 'U'
```

`xtype = 'U'` permite filtrar "tablas de usuario". Puedes combinar la consulta anterior, con la vista `syscolumns` de manera de ver las tablas con sus columnas:

```
select  o.name as tablename,
        c.name
        from master..sysobjects o
        inner join master..syscolumns c
          on o.id = c.id
        where o.xtype = 'U'
```

Estas vistas se han mantenido a lo largo de muchas versiones, sin embargo Microsoft recomienda usar las nuevas vistas `sys.objects` y `sys.columns`, entre otras ([ver documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-sysobjects-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)).

Answer (score 0):

para mostrar las tablas de la bd utilizas

```
show tables from NOMBRE_bd
```

para ver que contiene la tabla utilizas

```
Describe nombre_tabla
```

Answer (score 0):

Para ver todas las tablas de la base en específico

```
USE [NombreDB]
GO 
SELECT *
FROM sys.Tables
GO
```

Para ver todas las columnas de una tabla

```
SELECT column_name                  
FROM information_schema.columns     
WHERE table_name   = '[NombreTabla]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Para ver las tablas y sus columnas, tipo de columna y medidas :

```
SELECT A.NAME AS Tabla, B.COLUMN_NAME, B.DATA_TYPE, B.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH AS UNIDAD FROM sys.Tables A   LEFT JOIN information_schema.columns B 
ON A.NAME = B.TABLE_NAME  ORDER BY A.NAME, B.COLUMN_NAME;
```